# Given a POVM $\{F_j\}$ with $F_j=|\psi_j\rangle\!\langle\psi_j|$, what do the quantities $F_j|\phi\rangle$ and $\langle \psi_j|\phi\rangle$ represent?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, quantum-information, quantum-measurements

I mainly understand the concept of quantum measurement from an axiomatic viewpoint, and can't seem to find an answer to what I am wondering.  If it is addressed somewhere else, pointers and/or keywords to search would be greatly appreciated.

Consider a finite dimensional Hilbert space $H$, a density operator $\rho$, and a POVM $\{F_j\}$, where I assume all $F_j$'s to be rank-one for simplicity (say, $F_j = |\psi_j \rangle \langle \psi_j|$).  I understand that the probability of obtaining measurement outcome $j$ is given in this case by $\operatorname{tr}(F_j\rho) =  \langle \psi_j| \rho | \psi_j\rangle$, upon which the state collapses from $\rho$ to the pure state proportional to $F_j$.

Suppose our measurement produces outcome $j$.  My question is whether there is any meaning (physical or otherwise) associated to the quantities $F_j|\phi\rangle$ or $\langle\psi_j|\phi\rangle$, for a given $|\phi\rangle \in H$ (not necessarily a unit vector, or related to $\rho$ in any way)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They don't hold particular meaning, no. As always, $|\langle\psi_j|\phi\rangle|^2$ is the probability of finding $|\psi_j\rangle$ having $|\phi\rangle$, so $\langle\psi_j|\phi\rangle$ is a quantity whose absolute value equals the square root of such probability. Similarly, $F_j|\phi\rangle$ is the state $|\psi_j\rangle$ multiplied by a number that is related to the associated measurement probability.